# PHP MSQL form submit fail

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to create a new entry in the database by submitting the form data.
It does the whole code without any errors but doesn't show any new elements in the db.

Does anybody have any idea whats going on?

```
}elseif(isset($_GET["new"])){//add new 
        if($_GET['changeme']=="yes") //if user pressed save, then update table
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $active = $_POST["active"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $training = $_POST["training"];
        $trials = $_POST["trials"];
        $BHV = $_POST["BHV"];
        $tours = $_POST["tours"];
        $pasnr = $_POST["pasnr"];
        $pasactivated = $_POST["pasactivated"];
        $pastested = $_POST["pastested"];   

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Members (name, active, email, training, trials, BHV, tours, pasnr, pasactivates, pastested) VALUES
                    ('$name', '$active', '$email', '$training', '$trials', '$BHV', '$tours', '$pasnr', '$pasactivates', '$pastested')"); 
        //show end text
        echo "Edit complete!<br />
        <form><input type='button' onClick=\"parent.location='users.php'\" value='OK'></form>";
    }else{//user didn't press save

    ?>
    <!--Edit form-->
    <form action="users.php?new=1&changeme=yes" method="post">
    Name:<br>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="name" size="79"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="1" />Active 
    <input type="checkbox" name="BHV" value="1"  />BHV 
    <input type="checkbox" name="pasactivated" value="1"  />Pas activated 
    <input type="checkbox" name="pastested" value="1"  />Pas Tested <br>
    E-mail: <br>
    <input name="email" type="text" value="email" size="79"><br>
    Training Dates: <br>
    <input name="training" type="text" value="training" size="79"><br>
    Trial Dates: <br>
    <input name="trials" type="text" value="trials" size="79"><br>
    # Tours: <br>
    <input name="tours" type="text" value="tours" size="79"><br>
    Pas Nummer: <br>
    <input name="pasnr" type="text" value="pasnr" size="79"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Create">
    <input type='button' onClick="parent.location='users.php'" value='Back to list'>
    </form>

    <?
}}
```

Comment: Read up on `mysql_error()` and http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: You are my hero. :P But how exactly do I use the `mysql_error()` to find these tings in the future? (I used to have all errors on on my server, but now my host changed it so I'm not used to error handling in this way)

Comment: Ah ok, that works thanks. :P And this is also not very safe from what I understand?

Comment: So basically putting every var trough `$any_variable = mysql_real_escape_string($any_variable); ` is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code assumes that mysql_query() was successful without checking. The statement will return true if your query was successful and false if it was not. You should check the return value and use mysql_error() to get the error message as needed.

For debugging purposes, this can be accomplished as:

```
mysql_query(...) or die( mysql_query() )
```

However, in production code this could present ugly errors to users. A production-safe method is to log or email the errors:

```
$response = msyql_query('INSERT INTO ...');
if (false === $response) { 
    // Log or email the output of mysql_error()
}
```

When you implement error logging, you may find that your query is failing because of a mis-named variable. You assign a variable here:

```
$pasactivated = $_POST["pasactivated"];
```

but in the query, it is spelled differently:

```
mysql_query(...'$pasactivates'...);
```

Finally, you should note that your query leaves your database open to SQL injection attacks. All user input should be sanitized before insertion into a database. If you must use the `mysql_` functions, you can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape the input, but for best results, consider replacing the deprecated `mysql_*` functions with PDO and using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line instead :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Members (name, active, email, training, trials, BHV, tours, pasnr, pasactivates, pastested) VALUES
                    ('$name', '$active', '$email', '$training', '$trials', '$BHV', '$tours', '$pasnr', '$pasactivates', '$pastested')");
```

Remember to sanitize your variables before inserting them in this manner, or alternatively, you can use prepared statements.

Also, if possible, it is encouraged to use the mysqli extension instead of mysql.

Please read the following link which will help you handle mysql errors :

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php